# MpAndroid line Chart - want to show x axis labels like 125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to show axis labels like 125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000,... 
in Which next value is summation of value itself.

I have tried many ways but no result ,

```
XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();
xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
float i = 125f;
xl.setAxisMinimum(i);
xl.setAxisMaximum(8000f); 
xl.setGranularity(2*i);
```

and also tried ,

```
xAxis1.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatterIncome()); 

public class MyXAxisValueFormatterIncome extends ValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        try {
            if (value >= 125.0 && value <= 249) {
                return "125";
            } else if (value >= 250.0 && value <= 499) {
                return "250";
            } else if (value >= 500.0 && value <= 999.0) {
                return "500";
            } else if (value >= 1000.0 && value <= 1999.0) {
                return "1000";
            } else if (value >= 2000.0 && value <= 3999.0) {
                return "2000";
            } else if (value >= 4000.0 && value <= 7999.0) {
                return "4000";
            } else {  //if (value == 6.0)
                return "8000";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

however , it is also not working. 
Actually i want to show 125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000 - x axis labels , and  values can be varies from in between 125 to 8000. And Y axis values in between -10 to 120.
Please suggest workaround or any other ways.

Comment: R u looking for bar chart

Comment: no, line chart..

Comment: Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android)